# Export to Excel C# (Web Forms) function exporting an ASP grid suddenly not working and printing '<div>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms

I have a hidden grid that I am using to allow an ASP button to print some data to an Excel file, without displaying the grid on the page. This approach was working fine but suddenly the Excel file exported was simply printing `div` and `/div` in two different cells - and nothing else.

I will paste the button, the grid, the event, and the export service bellow.

The button:

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonExcelButton" runat="server" OnClick="ExcelButton_Click" CssClass="blue" Text="<i class='fas fa-file-excel'></i>" />
```

The grid:

```html
<asp:Panel ID="pnlHide" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:GridView ID="gridHidden" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="5" OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Workpackage" DataField="EXT_Workpackage_ID" SortExpression="Code" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Job" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job" DataField="name" SortExpression="Job" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Billing" DataField="billing" SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Allocated" DataField="Allocated_To" SortExpression="Billing" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Created Date" DataField="createdate" SortExpression="Allocated" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Earliest Start" DataField="earliest_start_date" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Latest Completion" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" DataField="latest_completion" SortExpression="Created" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Update" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" DataField="last_update" SortExpression="EarliestStart" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Actual" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="Actual" SortExpression="ProductionBudget" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Duration" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="child_duration" SortExpression="EstimatedMaterials" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Schedule A (£)" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="scheduleatotal" SortExpression="ScheduleA" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contract Type" DataField="contracttype" SortExpression="ContractType" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

The method:

```cs
protected void ExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExportService.ExportGrid(Response, gridHidden);
}
```

The export service:

```cs
public static void ExportGrid(HttpResponse response, GridView grid, string fileName = "Export", bool rebind = false)
{
    response.Clear();

    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
    response.Charset = "";

    // comment out line below to open excel sheet without saving local copy
    // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
    var stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    var htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    if (rebind)
    {
        grid.DataBind();
    }

    grid.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    response.End();
}
```

As stated this approach was working fine for months, but has recently given rise to this odd behaviour. I've looked into it and I still can't understand the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the raw response of the spreadsheet generation method?

Comment: How do I get the raw response of the spreadsheet generation method? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and web forms. Thanks